# Adapter public functions in c++ - good? bad? even a real pattern?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I use this pattern sometimes in code and I'm wondering if it's good, bad, or even has a name. I've done some research to see if it's a commonly used pattern to solve issues, but can't seem to find anything. What it helps me do is prevent knowledge of memory from being available to too many colleagues or peer objects. I guess an example would describe it best.

Suppose I have a game where a player has an inventory. The inventory has items, and each item has a databaseId, so that two copies of the same item can simply point to the same database entry. When something needs to take an item from the player's inventory, they don't have explicit knowledge of the item itself, and instead just know which item DB id they need to remove. Additionally, items are stored by their handleId (unique), which is used for client user interfaces (the unique handle is passed to the interface so that the UIItem basically has a sort-of callback id)

Psuedo-code:

```
class Inventory
    Map<int, Item> m_Items;
public:
    bool RemoveItem(int dbItemId, int count)
    {
        Item* pItem = GetItemByDBId(dbItemId);
        if (pItem) { return RemoveItem( pItem, count); }
        return false
    }
    bool RemoveItem(int handle, count)
    {
        Item* pItem = m_Items.Find(handle); //Find in my Map returns a const pointer.
        if (pItem) { return RemoveItem( pItem, count); }
        return false;
    }

private:
    bool RemoveItem(Item* item, int count); //Handles logic of removing, removes, and returns true if the remove succeeds (ie, quest items can't be removed, etc)
    Item* GetItemByHandle(int handle); //returns the item in the map by handle, null if not found
    Item* GetItemByDBId(int dbId); //returns the first item with this dbId, null if not found.
```

Now, if the UI wants to remove an item (ie, player dragged it into a trash bin) then there is a public method which decouples knowledge. If an NPC wants to remove an item (lets just say the NPC steals when it touches the player, and is looking for a particular ItemId) then it also has a public method which decouples knowledge.

My question is firstly, does this pattern have a name, or is it a variable of another pattern I'm not seeing? Secondly, is this good practice or bad practice? To me, it's good, but I might be missing something.

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me like a fairly textbook example of the [Flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).

> A flyweight is an object that minimizes memory use by sharing as much
>   data as possible with other similar objects; it is a way to use
>   objects in large numbers when a simple repeated representation would
>   use an unacceptable amount of memory. Often some parts of the object
>   state can be shared, and it is common practice to hold them in
>   external data structures and pass them to the flyweight objects
>   temporarily when they are used.

Comment: This object *contains* the actual data, it does not share or minimize any of the memory, it only provides a different interface than the container held internally

Comment: +1 David. I am using the flyweight pattern for optimizing the accessing the database, but accessing the item instance itself using the various public methods is what I'm asking about.